# What alternative for padStart

Tags: javascript

I'm using padStart in javascript but it's not working for internet explorer
I would like to know if someone know an alternative to replace this.
Thank you

Comment: The MDN gives a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart

Comment: When asking a question like this you should provide the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [a polyfill at the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart):

```
// https://github.com/uxitten/polyfill/blob/master/string.polyfill.js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart
if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
    String.prototype.padStart = function padStart(targetLength,padString) {
        targetLength = targetLength>>0; //truncate if number or convert non-number to 0;
        padString = String((typeof padString !== 'undefined' ? padString : ' '));
        if (this.length > targetLength) {
            return String(this);
        }
        else {
            targetLength = targetLength-this.length;
            if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                padString += padString.repeat(targetLength/padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
            }
            return padString.slice(0,targetLength) + String(this);
        }
    };
}
```

You can copy it in your script.